# Where rails store standard helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So where rails store its standard helpers, like form_tag - helper? i recently installed twetter-bottstrap-rails. So this gem provides some helpers that can be used in views to generate bootstrap-styled HTML. Where this helpers are stored? App/helpers - is empty - so this helpers must in the same place where standard rails helpers are.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter-bootstrap-rails helpers are in twitter-bootstrap-rails gem:

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/master/app/helpers

Answer (score 1):

Rails' `form_tag` is defined here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

However, that won't answer your question - the helpers that twitter-bootstrap-rails provides will be in the gem itself. See: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/master/app/helpers